# HTML5 Table Spacing and Alignment

Tags: css, html

I just finished the html portion of my table and need help with the css portion of it. The table can be found on this page: https://www.shiftins.com/test-page-1/.

My issue is with the alignment. I can't seem to figure out how to get 
the div "tbl-header" to align with div "tbl-content".

Also, I would like to know how to reduce the white space in between the county/city column and the start of the data set by slightly increasing the cell width into this space. How would I go about doing that for both sections of the table to keep everything aligned properly?

[image]

Comment: your code in your `td` is messed up `<td left;”="" style="“text-align:"`

Comment: Hey Dippas! Sorry I don't see what you are referring to

Comment: Post your code, not just an image and a link, this does no good for future visitors if the link goes bad, this question will not help anyone.

Comment: The table is like 3,500 lines. It won't fit.

Comment: You're over-complicating it. Use the HTML from my answer. When in doubt, check the standard itself. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The biggest problem I see is that your top row is in a different table than the rest of your data. You either need to specifically assign widths to each column, or put everything in the same table like this:

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d2o22955/)

```
<table class="sortable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width:80%;">
<tbody>

<tr>
<td style="text-align: left;"><strong>County / City</strong></td>
<td style="text-align: left;"><strong>200k</strong></td>
<td style="text-align: left;"><strong>300k</strong></td>
<td style="text-align: left;"><strong>400k</strong></td>
<td style="text-align: left;"><strong>500k</strong></td>
<td style="text-align: left;"><strong>750k</strong></td>
<td style="text-align: left;"><strong>Average</strong></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style="text-align: left;">ALAMEDA ALAMEDA</td>
<td style="text-align: left;">813.40</td>
<td style="text-align: left;">1144.72</td>
<td style="text-align: left;">1329.03</td>
<td style="text-align: left;">1636.41</td>
<td style="text-align: left;">2088.74</td>
<td style="text-align: left;">1402.46</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: left;">ALAMEDA BERKELEY</td>
<td style="text-align: left;">920.11</td>
<td style="text-align: left;">1297.82</td>
<td style="text-align: left;">1519.37</td>
<td style="text-align: left;">1872.77</td>
<td style="text-align: left;">2363.37</td>
<td style="text-align: left;">1594.69</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: left;">ALAMEDA FREMONT</td>
<td style="text-align: left;">735.92</td>
<td style="text-align: left;">1033.36</td>
<td style="text-align: left;">1203.48</td>
<td style="text-align: left;">1483.00</td>
<td style="text-align: left;">1871.16</td>
<td style="text-align: left;">1265.38</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hey Sawn, thank you. I did that so that it would have the "scrolling header" effect. Combining them into 1 table removes this. Is there any other way around it?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, a recommendation to create tables, try to avoid put in headers in  `<div>` tags and the data in other table, its better keep all the information in one table structure like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>title1</th>
    <th>title2</th> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data1</td>
    <td>data2</td> 
  </tr>
</table>
```

a `<th>` tag is a table headings, `<tr>` table rows and `<td>` table data

That's why the size of your table don't fit, so after made this change you can add css style of your table and works with the size of the rows http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp

Comment: Awesome explanation thank you. But how would I make the <th> "float" or scroll as I move down the table?

Comment: check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/dPixie/byB9d/3/

Answer (score 0):

How to do an (X)HTML5 table:

```
<table>
<colgroup style="width: 10%;"></colgroup>
<colgroup style="width: 30%;"></colgroup>
<colgroup style="width: 20%;"></colgroup>
<colgroup style="width: 20%;"></colgroup>
<colgroup style="width: 20%;"></colgroup>
<thead>
<tr><td>Column 1</td><td>Column 2</td><td>Column 3</td><td>Column 4</td><td>Column 5</td></tr>
</thead>
<tfoot>
<tr><td>Column 1</td><td>Column 2</td><td>Column 3</td><td>Column 4</td><td>Column 5</td></tr>
</tfoot>
<tbody>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the fixed header, you need to use 2 tables and assign fixed widths so that everything will line up.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vf0afxx5/1/)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>table alignment</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="author" content="shawn">

    <style>
        .aligned td{
            width:14% !important;
        }

        .aligned{
            width:70%; 
            margin-left:auto;
            margin-right:auto;          
         }

        .header{
            background:#0000ff;
            color:#fff;
            line-height:30px;
            height:30px;
            font-weight:bold;                       
      width:70%;
            left:15%;           
            top:0;
          position:fixed;
        }

      .clr30{
        clear:both;
        height:30px;
      }

    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <table class="aligned header">
        <tbody>             
            <tr>
            <td>County / City</td>
            <td>200k</td>
            <td>300k</td>
            <td>400k</td>
            <td>500k</td>
            <td>750k</td>
            <td>Average</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="clr30"></div>
    <table  class="aligned">
        <tbody>             
                <tr>
                <td>ALAMEDA ALAMEDA</td>
                <td>813.40</td>
                <td>1144.72</td>
                <td>1329.03</td>
                <td>1636.41</td>
                <td>2088.74</td>
                <td>1402.46</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>ALAMEDA BERKELEY</td>
                <td>920.11</td>
                <td>1297.82</td>
                <td>1519.37</td>
                <td>1872.77</td>
                <td>2363.37</td>
                <td>1594.69</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>ALAMEDA FREMONT</td>
                <td>735.92</td>
                <td>1033.36</td>
                <td>1203.48</td>
                <td>1483.00</td>
                <td>1871.16</td>
                <td>1265.38</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>ALAMEDA HAYWARD</td>
                <td>779.26</td>
                <td>1091.57</td>
                <td>1269.92</td>
                <td>1565.50</td>
                <td>1993.72</td>
                <td>1339.99</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>ALAMEDA LIVERMORE</td>
                <td>689.70</td>
                <td>973.33</td>
                <td>1140.16</td>
                <td>1410.07</td>
                <td>1762.98</td>
                <td>1195.25</td>
                </tr>                                                       
        </tbody>
    </table>

</html>
</body>
```